# How to get the position of all capture groups with quantifiers?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a small problem. I have a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) with multiple capture groups. Some of them have quantifiers (like '`+`'). If no quantifier is added, then `@-` & `@+` array are filled nicely with the matched position of the capture groups, but if a quantifier is added only the last match is detected. But I would like to have all of them.

An example:

```
my $s = 'xx1a2b3cyy';
my $re = qr/^xx(\d\w)+/;
```

So I'd like to know that matches are `'1a', '2b', '3c'` at 2, 4, 6.

Simple matching gives:

```
if ($s =~ $re) {
  print "Match @-, @+\n";
  for (my $i = 0; $i < @-; ++$i) {
    print 'i: ', $i, " - '", substr($s, $-[$i], $+[$i] - $-[$i]), "\n";
  }
}
```

Gives:

```
Match 0 6, 8 8
i: 0 - 'xx1a2b3c
i: 1 - '3c
```

So only the last capture group match is remembered.

My next simple try was which is not really what I want as the RE is different:

```
$re = qr/(\d\w)/;
my @s = ($s =~ /$re/g);
print "RE: '@s'\n";
while ($s =~ /$re/g) {
  print "Match @-, @+\n";
  for (my $i = 0; $i < @-; ++$i) {
    print 'i: ', $i, " - '", substr($s, $-[$i], $+[$i] - $-[$i]), "\n";
  }
}
```

gives:

```
RE: '1a 2b 3c'
Match 2 2, 4 4
i: 0 - '1a
i: 1 - '1a
Match 4 4, 6 6
i: 0 - '2b
i: 1 - '2b
Match 6 6, 8 8
i: 0 - '3c
i: 1 - '3c
```

But this not what I want, as it would match a string like `'ZZ1aAA2bBB3cZZ'`.

So somehow I have to combine the two. The best what I could get:

```
$re = '^xx(?:\d\w)*?\G(\d\w)';
pos($s) = 2;
while ($s =~ m($re)g) {
  print "Match pos: ", pos($s), ', G: ', $1, ", '@-', '@+'\n"
}
```

gives:

```
Match pos: 4, G: 1a, '0 2', '4 4'
Match pos: 6, G: 2b, '0 4', '6 6'
Match pos: 8, G: 3c, '0 6', '8 8'
```

This is almost nice, but for this I need to know the position of the first possible match. If it is not set properly it will not match anything. I can only determine the first position if I remove the non greedy part:

```
$re = '^xx(\d\w)';
if ($s =~ m($re)) {
  print "Match: '@-', '@+'\n";
}
```

which gives:

```
Match: '0 2', '4 4'
```

So `$-[1]` gives the first position, but for this I have to modify the RE "manually".

If I add code execution into the pattern I almost get what I need:

```
use re 'eval';
$re = '^xx(\d\w)+(??{print "Code: <@-> <@+>\n"})';
$s =~ m($re) and print "Match\n";
```

gives:

```
Code: <0 6> <8 8>
Code: <0 4> <6 6>
Code: <0 2> <4 4>
```

For this I need to add the `(?{ code })` part.

Does anybody know a simpler method (I mean not need to modify the original RE) to get all the possible matches of a capture group having a quantifier?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `my @matches = ( 'xx1a2b3cyy' =~ m/^xx(\d\w)+/ );` contains only `3c`. Using `use re 'debug'` on that tells us that it gets `1a`, `2b` and `3c` each as matches for the subpattern, but I have no idea where they end up. It looks like the last match of that first subpattern is saved as `$1` only, which explains why `@+` and `@-` only point to it.

Comment: @simbabque Yes, this is the same as 'Simple matching gives:' codelet gives. Anyway without the 'g' modifier it should not return more values.

Comment: But if you add a `/g` to my example, you also only get the last one.

Comment: @simbabque: Yes, you can get the last match, not all. It does not help me as I would like to have all. It seems only the `(?{ code })` may help... I have to check how it works with multiple capture groups with quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

There's no general solution; the regex engine simply doesn't store the necessary information. You're asking to use a regex as a parser, and that's a no-go.

---

```
sub extract {
   for ($_[0]) {
      /^ xx /xg
         or return ();

      my @matches;
      push @matches, $1 while /\G (\d\w) /xg;
      return @matches;
   }
}
```

or

```
sub extract {
   my ($pairs) = $_[0] =~ /^xx((?:\d\w)+)/
      or return ();

   return unpack('(a2)*', $pairs);
}
```

---

If you just want the positions, it's the same.

```
sub extract {
   for ($_[0]) {
      /^ xx /xg
         or return ();

      my @matches;
      push @matches, $-[1] while /\G (\d\w) /xg;
      return @matches;
   }
}
```

or

```
sub extract {
   $_[0] =~ /^xx((?:\d\w)+)/
      or return ();

   return map { $-[1] + ( $_ - 1 )*2 } 1..length($1)/2;
}
```

---

Even a non-general purpose solution is extremely hard using regular expressions. Say you had the following pattern:

```
xx(\d\w)+yy(\d\w)+zz
```

The correct solution would be:

```
use Storable qw( dclone );

my $s = "xx1a2byy3c4dZZ...xx5a6byy7c8dzz";

local our $rv;
if (
   $s =~ /
      (?{ [] })
      xx
      (?: (\d\w) (?{ my $r = dclone($^R); push @{ $r->[0] }, $^N; $r }) )+
      yy
      (?: (\d\w) (?{ my $r = dclone($^R); push @{ $r->[1] }, $^N; $r }) )+
      zz
      (?{ $rv = $^R; })
   /x
) {
   say "\$1: @{ $rv->[0] }";
   say "\$2: @{ $rv->[1] }";
}
```

Output:

```
$1: 5a 6b
$2: 7c 8d
```

And something like

```
(zz(\d\w)+)+
```

would need

```
use Storable qw( dclone );

my $s = "zz1a2bzz3c4d";

local our $rv;
if (
   $s =~ /
      (?{ [] })
      (?:
         (?{ my $r = dclone($^R); push @$r, []; $r })
         zz
         (?: (\d\w) (?{ my $r = dclone($^R); push @{ $r->[-1] }, $^N; $r }) )+
      )+
      (?{ $rv = $^R; })
   /x
) {
   say "\$1: @$_" for @$rv;
}
```

Output:

```
$1: 1a 2b
$1: 3c 4d
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Unfortunately they are fit to the current pattern in the example, and not a really RE independent solution. For example I have to now that the expression in the capture group is 2 char wide.

Comment: There's no general solution. You're asking to use a regex as a parser, and that's a no-go.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "you could use %- to some extent"? In my tries I can only find up to the number of actual capture groups with the same name as result, the quantifiers on them do not increase the number.  That would be the same to this problem as with positional captures. It would really help me if you can show me how you utilize `%-` better than that.

Comment: Nevermind, `%-` doesn't work as I thought it did. Removed that bit from my answer, and added another.

Comment: Thanks for the `$^R` / `$^N` examples, thought they would work only with lots and lots of `local` inside the embedded code before!

Comment: @SREagle, (Just one `local` per match operator.) It's truly complicated, yet that's what's required to do what you want using a single match.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can give some explanation for the behavior you see:

In the first example I can see only one capture group. The quantifier allows it to be used multiple times, but it's one capture group nonetheless. So every new occurence of a matching subpattern would overwrite the value previously captured there. Even if the RE engine is already advanced behind it, but backtracking would occur (for e.g. a more advanced pattern with branching and the likes), it could be that the now again visited capture group would change. And since `@-` and `@+` hold the positions to the capture groups (as opposed to occuring subpattern matches), this would explain why there's only the last occurence of the subpattern contained.

You could even play around with named subpatterns and `%+`/`%-` and would experience the same thing. It becomes more obvious with the already used `(?{ })`, at least for debugging purposes. But `use re 'debug'` is fine for shorter regexes / strings to match.

So be aware of the effects of backtracking to capture groups while matching is still in progress!

But if you don't have to care about backtracking, I can think of kind of a recipe to handle a capture group with a quantifier:

If your capture group is `(bla)` and your quantifier `{0,3}`, transform it into

`(?:(bla)(?{ print $-[$#-],$+[$#-]."\n" })){0,3}`.

You practically put the subpattern into another (non-capturing) group. If the RE engine is done with it, execute code regarding the last capture group matched so far. The quantifier outside the surrounding group is then responsible for the correct number of execution of the code fragment.

So you example becomes this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $s = 'xx1a2b3cyy';
my @submatches;
sub getem { push @submatches, [$-[$#-],$+[$#-]]; }
$s =~ m/^xx(?:(\d\w)(?{ getem() }))+/;
print Dumper(\@submatches);
```

This also works with multiple capture groups transformed this way:

```
my $s = 'xx1a2b3cyy4de5fg6hihhh2';
$s =~ m/^xx(?:(\d\w)(?{ getem() }))+yy(?:(\d\w{2})(?{ getem() }))+hh/;
```

You have to adjust the index used, if your capture group contains more capture groups. That's why I prefer names capture groups.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You still have to check for an overall match - the embedded code gets executed immediately, if reached by the RE engine. Putting a `z` after the `+` results in a fail, but `@submatches` still contains all triggered submatches

Comment: Instead of `z` `(*FAIL)` might be used, so the backtracking engine will try all matches.

Comment: My point seems to haven't come across: If the match as a whole fails, the captured positions are probably not what you're looking for. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That still uses `(?{ })` which the question specifically asks to remove. And if you're going to use `(?{ })`, you're doing it all wrong -- backtracking doesn't remove matches you've stored. You gotta use `$^R` (and you should be using `$^N` instead of that complicated expression).

Comment: That backtracking doesn't remove the stored subpattern matches is EXACTLY what I repeatedly tried to say here, but thanks for repating it, maybe the rephrasing let's it get understood! And the usage of `(?{ })`isn't specifically be asked to be removed - the OP tries it himself for solving his problem - so I gave it another shot. If you like, you can demonstrate your $^R / $^N approach in an extra section - I'm always willing to learn.

Comment: Re "*And the usage of (?{ })isn't specifically be asked to be removed*", Look again, the question is for a better alternative than inserting `(?:{ })`. They have since re-asserted that by saying they want something that works for any RE.

Comment: If you look at it that way, you're right. I mistook the problem to solve for the first 7 lines. Starting with "Simple matching gives:" is for me a number of his tries at a solution for his stated problem, and I saw it as invitation to improve on them. That seems to be a "no-go" for you. And my approach specifically restricts the usage to REs NOT involving foreseeable backtracking. If this helps him in any way, this would bring him closer to solving his problem than none at all. If not, he does not have to do anything with it, so where's the harm?

Comment: Re "*And my approach specifically restricts the usage to REs NOT involving foreseeable backtracking.*", Which a fancy way of saying it almost never works. For example, it doesn't work if you remove the `^`.

Comment: That's correct. Although the `^` example isn't the best: For determining the positions in the string to match - his problem to solve - anchoring it to the start is kind of the point. That's why half of his tries and your first four use it too, I guess. Anyway: Thumbs (and vote) up for your last examples!